# Square root of compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I'm trying to solve a functional analysis problem

A self-adjoint non-negative operator $A$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is compact if and only if its $\sqrt{A}$ is compact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $A^{1/2}$ is compact, $A = A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$ is as a composition of a compact and a bounded operator is compact.

If, on the other hand, $A$ is compact, we can write $A = \sum_{n\ge 1} \lambda_n(\cdot, x_n)x_n$ for some $\lambda_n \to 0$ and an orthonormal sequence (the $\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $x_n$ are the corresponding eigenvectors. Then $A^{1/2} = \sum_{n\ge 1} \lambda_n^{1/2}(\cdot, x_n)x_n$ is compact as it is the limit (in the norm topology) of the finite dimensional operators $B_N = \sum_{1\le n \le N} \lambda_n^{1/2}(\cdot, x_n)x_n$ since $\|B_N - A^{1/2}\| \le \lambda_N^{1/2} \to 0$.

Comment: But why $A^{1/2}$ equals $\sum_{n\ge 1} \lambda_n^{1/2}(\cdot, x_n)x_n$

Comment: @user31919: Did you try squaring it?

Comment: @user31919 Let $B = \sum_{n\ge 1} \lambda_n^{1/2}(\cdot, x_n)x_n$. Then $B$ is self-adjoint and non-negative, moreover for $x\in H$ we have $$ B(Bx) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \lambda_n^{1/2}(Bx, x_n)x_n = \sum_{n,m\ge 1} \lambda_n^{1/2}\lambda_m^{1/2}(x, x_m)(x_m, x_n)x_n = \sum_{n\ge 1}\lambda_n (x,x_n)x_n = Ax $$ and so $B = A^{1/2}$.

Comment: @martini I see,i got it already! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So this argument shows also that if A is compact and positive, then it has the same range as $A^{1/2}$, right?

Comment: @DA1729 No. Consider $A\colon (x_n) \mapsto (x_n/n)$ on $\ell^2$. Then $A^{1/2} \colon (x_n)\mapsto (x_n/n^{1/2})$. Note that $(1/n^{3/2}) \in \mathop{\rm rng}(A^{1/2})$, as $(1/n) \in \ell^2$, but $(1/n^{3/2}) \not\in \mathop{\rm rng}(A)$.

Comment: Why is $\|B_N - A^{1/2}\| \le \lambda_N^{1/2}$

Comment: @martini Why is A^{1/2} well-defined? Why can we just write it down like this?

Comment: The problem is that we can only write $Sx$ like this for $x\in\overline{\text{lin}(x_1,x_2,...)}$ and have to set $Sx=0$ for $x\in\ker(T)$ because $H=\ker(T)\oplus\overline{\text{lin}(x_1,x_2,...)}$.